# Toggle after back button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello people i have this code....

```
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com /ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".mytableCol3").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("on").parent().siblings("tr").find("td").removeClass("on");
    });
});
</script>
<style>
    .on { background-color:red; color:#ffffff; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table class="mytable" border=1>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="mytableCol3"><a href="google.com">google</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="mytableCol3"><a href="yahoo.com">yahoo</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="mytableCol3"><a href="bing.com">bing</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="mytable" border=1>
</body>
</html>
```

above code is working fine by toggling red color between cells and it also redirects page to "specific location" when clicked on it.please check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UQBHH/2/) ,you can observ first the cell goes red color then it will be redirected to google/yahoo/bing ,but now what iam need to do when they come back to by clicking back button /(code what i write) ,specific cell which was selected should still be highlighted with red color.... i reied doing this by session but not exactly.. can any one plzz help me to fix this....

Comment: Can you post the code in which you tried to do it with a SESSION?

Comment: Unless your page needs to support ie7, use html5 web storage: http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/

Comment: You have an empty unclosed `table` tag at the end too.

Comment: This looks like one of the few places where `target=_blank` would be appropriate.

Comment: You should break your question into sentences and use proper case. It's hard to get your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [$.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Assign an ID for each line and set cookie, then check that cookie for an available id:

```
<table class="mytable" border=1>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="mytableCol3" id="google"><a href="http://google.com">google</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="mytableCol3" id="yahoo"><a href="http://yahoo.com">yahoo</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="mytableCol3" id="bing"><a href="http://bing.com">bing</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​
```

and javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $(".mytableCol3").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("on").parent().siblings("tr").find("td").removeClass("on");
        $.cookie('clicked', $(this).attr('id'));
    });

    if($('#'+$.cookie('clicked'))){
        $('#'+$.cookie('clicked')).addClass('on');
    }
});
```

​
You can use plain javascript for cookie, I used that [plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for [example](http://jsfiddle.net/n9uGH/).

Comment: good technique... but still understanding how exactly you have used that plugin...:(

Comment: just setting and getting a cookie.

Comment: i have setup the plugin but here is my code ... `$(document).ready(function(){
$("td.mytableCol3").live("click", function () 
{  
 
 $('.mytableCol3').css('background-color','#FFFFFF');
 $(this).css('background-color','green');
 $.cookie('clicked', $(this).attr('id'));
 
});   

if($('#'+$.cookie('clicked'))){
        $('#'+$.cookie('clicked')).css('background-color','green');
    }


});`  is it correct?

Comment: i dont know how to configure that plugin in fiddle.. but i checked the above in fiddle by replace your code jquery .. and its working fine.... may its an issue with configuring plugin....dont know how to fix.. still researching...

Comment: use [THIS LINK](https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js) in Add Resources.

Comment: i have added `<script src="https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js"></script>` in header session...but still no go:(

Comment: did you added `id` for each `td` ? And you should download that plugin and use it from your hdd

Comment: you need to set an ID for each `td` otherwise you can't know what `td` it is

Comment: hmm sorry i did not get what's the id name i can use....???as per this code  `$(document).ready(function(){ $("td.mytableCol3").live("click", function () { $('.mytableCol3').css('background-color','#FFFFFF'); $(this).css('background-color','green'); $.cookie('clicked', $(this).attr('id')); }); if($('#'+$.cookie('clicked'))){ $('#'+$.cookie('clicked')).css('background-color','green'); } });`

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` gets the id from the clicked td `<td class="mytableCol3" id="google">` => `id="google"`!

Comment: great ! i got it.. thanks alot .. you are just an amasing guy,i ever seen such a helpfull guy in my life.. thanks alot for spending so much of time....god bless you....